# Returning the entity with max number of participants

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm using pgsql to find the cage number (cno) that holds the largest number of animals but doesn't have a bird in it.

The way I tried to do it is by creating a table that counts the number of animals in each cage (not including those with birds) and then return the ones where the count equals the max value.

```
select temp.cno,temp.size
from
(select cage.cno,cage.size,count(*) as q
from cage,animal
where cage.cno = animal.cno  and cage.cno not in (select cno from animal where lower(atype)='sheep')
group by cage.cno,cage.size) as temp
where temp.q = (select max(q) from temp)
```

I'm getting the following error message

```
ERROR:  relation "temp" does not exist
LINE 7: where temp.q = (select max(q) from temp)
```

Any idea how to overcome this issue? Why isn't temp recognized within the last sub query?

Here are the tables

1. cage (**cno**, type, size)
2. animal (**aid**, aname, cno, atype)

Comment: Please post the schema, at least partial.

Comment: @OliverWeichhold Added the 2 relevant tables hope this is what you meant

Comment: The table definitions.

Comment: I suspect that in your query `'sheep'` should be `'bird'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by ordering the results descending and using limit 1 to show the first row (which is the max)

Comment: Post the query that you use to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You already found out that a subquery defined in the `FROM` is not visible inside another subquery defined in the `WHERE` clause.

This is easily solvable with the use of a `CTE` (with a proper join):

```
WITH temp AS (
  SELECT c.cno, c.size, COUNT(*) AS q
  FROM cage c INNER JOIN animal a
  ON a.cno = c.cno  
  WHERE c.cno NOT IN (SELECT cno FROM animal WHERE LOWER(atype) = 'bird')
  GROUP BY c.cno, c.size
)
SELECT cno, size
FROM temp
WHERE q = (SELECT MAX(q) FROM temp);
```

But, if there is a case that in a cage exist animals of more than one type then the condition:

```
c.cno NOT IN (SELECT cno FROM animal WHERE LOWER(atype) = 'bird')
```

is not correct, because it returns all cages which contain other types than birds without a restriction that there are *only* other types than birds.

You can apply this restriction with aggregation.

If you want/expect only 1 cage as result:

```
SELECT c.cno, c.size
FROM cage c INNER JOIN animal a
ON a.cno = c.cno
GROUP BY c.cno
HAVING MAX((LOWER(a.atype) = 'bird')::int) = 0
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1;
```

If you want more than one cages with the largest number of animals, use `RANK()` window function:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT c.cno, c.size,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
  FROM cage c INNER JOIN animal a
  ON a.cno = c.cno
  GROUP BY c.cno
  HAVING MAX((LOWER(a.atype) = 'bird')::int) = 0
)  
SELECT cno, size FROM cte WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Note that since `cno` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of `cage` you only need to group by `cno`.